# Find the function that describes a real life curve

Tags: calculus, geometry

Let's say you want to compute the length of an arbitrary 2 dimensional curve or the area between two arbitrary 2 dimensional curves in the real world. For example you take your pen and draw a line and you want to know the length of it. How do you do it? I mean is there a technique? We can compute the lengths or the areas of basic geometric shapes like circles and straight lines. Is there a way that we can "translate" a given graph in the real world to a function type and use calculus tools to compute such kind of things?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is indeed an instrument which can measure the area enclosed by a free handed drawn curve. The method is simply to approximate with a polygon, for which there is an easy formula. But I do not remember the name of this instrument.

Comment: With this tool, you can measure the size of countries or similar geographic objects.

Comment: Planimeter. I used one long ago in a real life application (finding the areas fields from a picture taken from an airplane, in a setting where each farmer was allowed to plant at most a set number of acres).

Comment: Ok about the planimeter. But mathematically is there a way to "translate" a given graph to a function type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup, regression analysis/method of least squares. you would assign a coordinate system to the plane on which the curve is located and measure the coordinates of various points on the graph. the regression analysis will fit these curves to a function of your choice such as polynomial, exponential, etc. (the choice is a matter of which one you judge will be the best fit) and assign the relevant constants.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Regression analysis with least of squares method makes sense!